# iOS UIWebView Javascript Timers

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiwebview, ios8

If a page loaded into a `UIWebView` contains a Javascript `setInterval()` call, what is the behavior of that timer when the phone goes sleep?

Is there any point in time when all timers are stopped?

Will the timers be restarted when the phone is woken up?  If so, does the timer start at where it was paused, or started from 0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WebKit internal timer management is a little peculiar in general, and in particular in iOS. They are registered in NSDefaultRunLoopMode mode, so for example, when scrolling in UI, Javascript events do not fire, but they are not aggregated either, like with regular timers (`NSTimer`).

To answer your question, when the application process is suspended, the timers are also suspended, so they will not fire while the process remains suspended. Once the process is resumed for whatever reason (user opened the app, background fetch, etc.), the timers will resume their run, and will resume to the relative point of when the last tick was supposed to be.

So if you set a timer for every 10 seconds, and close the app at t+1 seconds, then open it again at t+35 seconds, the timer will fire after 5 seconds; you would not hear retroactively the t+10, t+20 and t+30 seconds ticks.

**Note:** This is the in-process model based timer management of `UIWebView` /WebKitLegacy/; I am not quite experienced with how `WKWebView` /WebKit2/ handles them.

Comment: Great answer. Is there any point in time where the timers and/or the JS would be reclaimed/stopped.  We are experiencing an issue where after a certain period of time the timers no longer fire even when the app is brought into the foreground. I notice after a long amount of time (say 6-12 hours) when bringing the app in the foreground, the JS files are re-downloaded.  I would expect the timers to resume as well, but they are not.

Comment: @Steve I am not familiar with this issue. It sounds as if WebKit attempts to reload freed resources from cache and does so in a bad manner. I would asset that the framework is not taking into account such scenarios. Perhaps it might be a better solution to use NSTimers and trigger the JS code using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`. This would introduce a much more ordered and predictable behavior.

Comment: Ok, that is essentially what we ended up doing, and are executing JS to restart the timers each time the app comes to the foreground. Thanks.